# Who invented bit permutations like shuffle, butterfly and bit-reversal?

Tags: mathematicians, computer-science, combinatorics

This question is about a class of periodic permutations,
that are produced by applying finite permutations to the binary digits of all integers.
In lack of a better name, they shall be called *bit permutations* for now.

Some of these permutations are often called *shuffle*, *butterfly* and *bit-reversal*,
which can be prepended by *sub*, *super*, and *perfect*.
E.g. "k sub-butterfly" or "perfect shuffle".

The simplest example is exchanging the two least significant bits. ([Sloane's A080412](https://oeis.org/A080412))
Well-known examples are the [bit-reversal permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit-reversal_permutation). ([Sloane's A030109](https://oeis.org/A030109))

Within this question I will denote the sequences as follows:
Let p<sub>*n*</sub> be the *n*-th finite permutation. (See [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Symmetric_group_4;_permutation_list_(0-based).svg) list.)
Then S<sub>*n*</sub> shall be the sequence obtained by applying p<sub>*n*</sub> on the binary digits of all integers.
See [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Consecutive_bit_permutations_24x16.svg) 24×16 matrix, whose rows are S<sub>0</sub> ... S<sub>23</sub>. ([Sloane's A195665](https://oeis.org/A195665))
(These sequences are not the permutations, but the results of applying them – but never mind.)

Below are the first 6 finite permutations assigned to S<sub>0</sub> ... S<sub>5</sub>.
The 6×8 matrix is the top left corner of the 24×16 matrix.

```
[0, 1, 2]   -->   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 0, 2]   -->   [0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7]
[0, 2, 1]   -->   [0, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 7]
[2, 0, 1]   -->   [0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7]
[1, 2, 0]   -->   [0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7]
[2, 1, 0]   -->   [0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7]
```

#### Question

Who came up with this?
What are the earliest examples of permutations like these (except perfect bit-reversals).
Ideally, I would like to know the oldest source that shows the first 6 or 24 examples together.
There should certainly be something older than [A195665](https://oeis.org/A195665), which I published in 2011.

(I am hoping for something with the clarity of [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rothe_Stellenexponenten_2.jpg) source, where one can see,
that Rothe has essentially defined the factorial number system around the year 1800.)

#### Sources

##### misc.

Searching for specific bit permutations leads to all kinds of technical sources.
[Here](https://www.mvtec.com/doc/halcon/1811/en/hit_or_miss_golay.html) and [there](https://github.com/Mysticial/DigitViewer/blob/master/Source/DigitViewer2/DigitHash/Kernels/DigitHash_x64_AVX2.h) are examples for "0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15". (S<sub>9</sub>)
[Here](https://www.informatik.hu-berlin.de/de/forschung/gebiete/algorithmenII/Lehre/ss06/krypto2/skript/kap1.pdf) and [there](https://github.com/Ledger-Donjon/rainbow/blob/master/examples/hacklu2009/go.py) are examples for "0, 4, 8, 12, 1, 5, 9, 13, 2, 6, 10, 14, 3, 7, 11, 15". (S<sub>16</sub>)

##### Bhujade (1995)

*Parallel Computing*, Moreshwar R. Bhujade

On pages 164–166 are the chapters *Perfect Shuffle Permutations*, *Butterfly Permutation* and *Bit Reversal Permutations*. The perfect shuffle is [this rotation](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Walsh_permutation_241.svg). The other examples are called (sub/super) butterfly and (sub/super) bit-reversal. (The butterflies and bit-reversals are the same in this case, because the examples use only 3 bits.)

##### Bhattacharyya et al. (2003)

*Domain-Specific Processors: Systems, Architectures, Modeling, and Simulation*
Shuvra S. Bhattacharyya, ‎Ed F. Deprettere, ‎Jürgen Teich

The [figure on page 72](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Signal-flow-graphs-of-FFT-algorithms-a-radix-2-and_fig1_248853426) shows two transformations:
(a) from S<sub>23</sub> to S<sub>18</sub> using 2-point FFT
(b) from S<sub>16</sub> to itself using 4-point FFT

The caption is: Signal flow graphs of FFT algorithms:
(a) radix-2 and (b) radix-4 algorithm

##### Dally, Towles (2004)

*Principles and Practices of Interconnection Networks*
William James Dally, ‎Brian Patrick Towles

S<sub>9</sub> is described as a *shuffle permutation* on page 57.

> For bit-rotation (BR) traffic, the node with address {b<sub>3</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>0</sub>}
> sends packets only to the node with address {b<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>0</sub>, b<sub>3</sub>}.
> Expressed differently, this traffic corresponds to the shuffle
> permutation {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15}

##### Lee, Ye (2018)

[*A Relational Approach to Functional Decomposition of Logic Circuits*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0611024.pdf) (PDF on Arxiv)
The figure on page 14 shows S<sub>3</sub> and S<sub>12</sub>.

Comment: There are more things than names, so not all things have good names. The search for a better name is in fact my main reason to ask this question. As you can see from the four linked examples, these permutations are mainly used in computer science. (Especially in cryptography, it seems.)

Comment: I do not intend to enter into a discussion on terminology. To the best of my knowledge: For practical use, the first bit permutation used in CS was bit reversal for FFT, followed in the 1970s by uses of bit permutation in cryptography. I *assume* this latter use case prompted Cray to *invent* a hardware mechanism for generalized bit permutation in 1990 (the bit matrix multiply). Many modern processors provide (limited) mechanisms for applying bit permutations.

Comment: That would be Seymour Cray?

Comment: Cray as in [Cray Research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray), a company founded by Seymour Cray. United States [patent 5,170,370](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5170370A/en) "Vector bit-matrix multiply functional unit", filed in 1990, lists the following inventors: William Lee, Gary J. Geissler, Steven J. Johnson, Alan J. Schiffleger

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find any old sources that do show these permutations. The most interesting source I have found until now is [this image](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Signal-flow-graphs-of-FFT-algorithms-a-radix-2-and_fig1_248853426) from the Bhattacharyya book. (But that is from 2003.) @njuffa Do you understand this image? And do you see a reason, why these three permutations are used?

Comment: Modern FFT goes back to James W. Cooley and John W. Tukey, "An Algorithm for the Machine Calculation of Complex Fourier Series." *Mathematics of Computation*, Vol. 19, No. 90, 1965, pp.  297-301 (free access at [AMS](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1965-19-090/home.html)). Equation 14 seems to specify the bit reversal used in indexing. The Data Encryption Standard (DES) released in 1975 (developed by IBM in the early 1970s) features various bit permutations (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES_supplementary_material) for example).

Comment: The researcher who to my knowledge has worked most intensely on modern bit-manipulation primitives, since at least the year 2000, is R. B. Lee (now Princeton, formerly Hewlett-Packard). Her publications *may* include some historical notes on the use of bit permutations. Example: Z. Shi and R. B. Lee, "Bit permutation instructions for accelerating software cryptography." In *Proceedings IEEE International Conference on Application-Specific Systems, Architectures, and Processors*, July 2000, pp. 138-148